# Spark structure stream as downstream consumer of kafka stream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka streams application, and i want to write in s3 using delta table from databricks via spark.

However my kafka stream application use Exactly once processing and it seems that spark does not provide the option to set the consumer isolation level to READ_COMMITTED.

Hence, do i need to remove exactly once processing from my kafka streams application, or are there workaround ?

Comment: Spark uses checkpoints for exactly once, but sounds like you're asking for something else?

Comment: Indeed, what I would like to know is how to set up the spark consumer to read from a topic that has transactions markers. If I can’t configure the consumer to be read_commited then my assumption is that it will read everything, markers or record from aborted transactions and what not. In that case, how to filter at least the transaction marker out when readying from a topic ?

Comment: Is the consumer used by spark even compatible with topics that have transactions ? I can’t remove transaction because it is not the only consumer, others in my pipeline rely on it.

Comment: I've not used Spark since transactions were added to Kafka, but I assume you'd need to use Spark filter function on the initial bytes to exclude processing them from any stream, before casting/parsing the data any further

Comment: That is really unfortunate :( !  Not sure what that will really entail :( !! It might not just be a filter here. Essentially it is the entire logic of consuming from transaction that would need to be re-implemented. E.g. As long as a transaction is not closed, the poll should not return anything .... although the fetch keep fetching and what not. Unless i misunderstood what you mean by  initial bytes

Comment: When you use Spark sql, then kafka messages are always consumed as bytes and so if you want to exclude transactional kafka events, you'd have to filter them out before deserializing the other producer events... I'm not sure what it'll look like either